# Grade and projdim of finite modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, cohen-macaulay

I am reading *Cohen-Macaulay Rings* by Bruns & Herzog, and trying to prove the lemma below:

**Lemma.** Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, and let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Then for all $\mathfrak{p}\in\mathop{\mathrm{Supp}}M$,
$$
\mathop{\mathrm{grade}}M\leq \mathop{\mathrm{grade}}M_\mathfrak{p}\leq \mathop{\mathrm{proj\,dim}}M_\mathfrak{p}\leq \mathop{\mathrm{proj\,dim}}M.
$$
**What I have already thought**

- The first inequality immediately follows from the definition of grade
  $$
  \mathop{\mathrm{grade}} M = \inf\{i\geq 0 \mid\mathop{\mathrm{Ext}}\nolimits_{R}^{i}(R/\mathop{\mathrm{Ann}} M, R)\neq 0\},\\
  \mathop{\mathrm{grade}} M_\mathfrak{p} = \inf\{i\geq 0 \mid\mathop{\mathrm{Ext}}\nolimits_{R_\mathfrak{p}}^{i}(R_\mathfrak{p}/\mathop{\mathrm{Ann}} M_\mathfrak{p}, R_\mathfrak{p})\neq 0\}
  $$
  and the fact that under this circumstance Ext commutes with the localization $-\otimes R_\mathfrak{p}$.
- The third inequality immediately follows from the fact that, by the localization $-\otimes R_\mathfrak{p}$, all projective resolutions of $M$ give projective resolutions of $M_\mathfrak{p}$.

**Question.**
How to prove the second inequality $\mathop{\mathrm{grade}}M_\mathfrak{p}\leq \mathop{\mathrm{proj\,dim}}M_\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: Definition 1.2.11 may help.

Comment: What you imply is to see the exact sequence $0\to \mathfrak{p}R_{\mathfrak{p}}\to R_{\mathfrak{p}}\to k\to 0$ and the long exact Ext sequence, right ?

Comment: We may assume $R$ is local. Since $\operatorname{Ext}(M,N)$ is computed from a free resolution of $M$, we see that  if $\operatorname{Ext}_R^i(M,N)\neq 0$ for any module $N$, then $\operatorname{pd}_RM\geq i$. Take $N=R$ and use definition 1.2.11.

Comment: OK your answer is very clear and modified the proof of the first inequality too. Thanks for your kindness.